# Select the non-null value in group by (complex map)

Tags: sql, hive

I want to reduce a dimension on a hive table that contains complex map columns. For each row in the input table only one column contains a complex map (i.e. `MAP<STRING, STRUCT<...>>`). All other columns are null. It looks like this:

| ID | Type | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "A" | "field1" | field1_map | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| "A" | "field2" | NULL | field2_map | NULL | NULL |
| "B" | "field3" | NULL | NULL | field3_map | NULL |
| "B" | "field4" | NULL | NULL | NULL | field4_map |

[image: somehow s.overflow doesnt render table markdown]

Normally this can be achieved by

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(field_1),
    MAX(field_2),
    MAX(field_3),
    MAX(field_4)
FROM 
    input_table
GROUP BY ID
```

Because normally MAX function selects the only non-null cell from the result set. However complex maps are not orderable so MAX function doesn't work on them and return an error. Is there any alternative solution or function that can be used instead of MAX to select the non null value?

The obvious solution involves using select statements for each fieldX column and joining them on `ID` but I am looking for a more performant/trivial solution as the number of fields can get very large.

Comment: The first not-null value according to what order? Could we rely on the `Type` column to get the order?

Comment: In the input_table there's only a single `fieldX` column in each row that is not null, and that column name is specified by the `Type`. The order doesn't matter in that regard, I just want to select the non null value for each `fieldX` column by `ID`.

Comment: Maybe the first_value function works for you, https://dbfiddle.uk/1O8yJTQV